# How do I refactor a script that uses argparse to be callable inside another Python script?

Tags: python, refactoring, argparse

I have a script that finds test names and is widely used in our company. It operates on the command line like so:

```
find_test.py --type <type> --name <testname>
```

Inside the script is the equivalent of:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Test Path')
parser.add_argument('--type',      dest='TYPE',      type=str,            default=None,  help="TYPE [REQUIRED]")
parser.add_argument('--name',      dest='test_name', type=str,            default=None,  help="Test Name (Slow)")
parser.add_argument('--id',        dest='test_id',   type=str,            default=None,  help="Test ID (Fast)")
parser.add_argument('--normalise', dest='normalise', action="store_true", default=False, help="Replace '/' with '.' in Test Name")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

(Not sure what all these arguments do, I personally only use the first two). These lines are then proceeded by the code that uses these arguments.

I want to refactor this script so I can import it as a module, but also preserve its command line functionality - since lots of people use this script and it is also called in some of our csh scripts.

I have refactored it so far, like so:

```
def _main():
    <all the former code that was in find_test.py>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

And this still runs fine from the command line. But I don't know how then in my parent script I pass arguments with the relevant switches into this.

How do I refactor this further and then call it in parent script?
Is this possible?

I'd also rather not use docopts which i've read is the new argparse unless necessary - i.e. can't be done with argparse, since it's not installed company wide and this can be an arduous procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't just move all the code directly into a function; that doesn't help at all.

What you should do is move the code that needs to run whatever happens into a function. (And since it is the external interface, it should not begin with `_`.) The code that only needs to run from the command line - ie the parser stuff - should *stay* in the `__name__ == '__main__'` block, and it should pass its results to `main()`.

So:

```
def main(TYPE, test_name, test_id=None, normalise=False):
    # ... body of script...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ...
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```

(And docopt isn't the new anything; it's an external library which some people like.)